# Украинский: правильное ударение

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Как правильно: **укрАинский** или **украИнский**? Где поставить ударение?

Я думаю, что правильно **украИнский** (ударение на "и"). Говорю всегда исключительно с ударением на данную букву. А все вокруг (большинство и моего окружения, и по телевизору часто слышу) делают ударение на "а". Ну почему? Как объяснить, что ударение все же на "и"? (так же правильно, да?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Правильно украИнский (от слова УкраИна, украИнцы). Так что Вы правильно произносите название страны и производные  слова.

Comment: Уши режет не правильное произношение. Но люди (которые живут в Украине - украИнцы) произносят не правильно. В чем проблема? Не уважают свою нацию? Не знают? Издеваются?

Comment: >люди (которые живут в Украине - украИнцы) произносят не правильно.

Некоторые, только некоторые, произносят не правильно.

Правильное ударение в русс. языке вам уже указали выше. Правильное ударение в укр. языке аналогичное, на тот же слог, что и в русском, например -- украЇнський хлопець.

Comment: Можно уточнить? "Українська мова" - тоже ударение на Ї? Я постоянно слышу ударение на а.

Comment: УкраЇна, украЇнська мова, украЇнець, украЇнка. С ударением на А -разговорный вариант.

Comment: Вообще интересно, потому-что я ещё не втречала не российского человека который произносил бы это слово с ударением на И. Ещё один пример "неправильного" ударения: "И бесстрашно отряд поскакал на врага / По широкой УкрАинской степи" (Там вдали, за рекой). Я всегда считала что это мы, Россияне, произносим неправильно, поэтому очень удивилась, увидав Ваш ответ. А с этимологической точки зрения, можно ли аргументировать что корень КРАЙ и поетому ударение надо на А? А если нет, то почему-же всё-таки на И? Спасибо!

Comment: Я **укра*и*нец**, живу в **Укра*и*не**. В **укра*и*нском** языке тоже, как и в русском, правильным считается делать ударение на звук "и": **Укра*ї*на**, **укра*ї*нець**, **укра*ї*нський**.
Однако, что касается слова "украинский", то даже мы сами часто произносим его с ударением на звук "а" (это касается исключительно слова укр*а*инский, слова Укра*и*на, укра*и*нец и тем более Укра*ї*на, укра*ї*нець, укра*ї*нський -- язык не поворачивается сказать по-другому).
Почему так происходит -- не знаю. Возможно сказывается родственная связь со словами край, окраинный, возможно Пушкин с его "Полтавой".

Comment: Я от самих украинцев слышал и украИнец и укрАинец. Причем от западноукраинцев, у которых родной язык украинский.

Answer (score 8):

[По ссылке](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkvUb27xh5Y) видео с отрывком лекции А. А. Зализняка, где он объясняет и почему распространено ударение на "а", и откуда пришло ударение на "и".

Answer (score 7):

В русском языке ударение - это больше чем ударение, это неиссякаемый источник самых разнообразных чувств, в то время как, казалось бы, факту существования вариантных ударений следует дать объективную оценку и установить причину этого явления.

Современные словари очень принципиальны по отношению к слову "украИнский". Вот академический словарь Аванесова (1987 год) строго предупреждает: ударение только на И, не рекомендуется устаревшее "укрАинский".

Словарь Резниченко (2003 год) слово "укрАинский" называет старой нормой, сетуя, однако, на обыденную речь, а также на поэтов, эту норму нарушающих. Вот, к примеру, О. Мандельштам: "В гуще воздуха степного Перекличка поездов Да укрАинская мова Их растянутых гудков". Кстати, называется и причина: "укрАинский" - от устаревшего "УкрАйна".

Вот бы интересно проследить историю:  что и когда говорили нам орфоэпические словари, в каком году устарела одна норма и появилась другая и как всё это объясняют ученые-филологи. В любом случае, устойчивое колебание в ударении, которое наблюдается в речи большого количества достаточно образованных людей, - это повод для размышления, а не для столь ярких и разрушительных эмоций.

Comment: По-русски до совсем недавних времен говорилось только "укрАинский", "укрАинец", от "укрАйна". В Московском государстве "укрАинцами" изначально называли воинских людей (пограничников), несших службу на окской Украйне - в Верхнем и Среднем Поочье - против крымцев. И на самой Украине была та же история, У Шевченко найдем и "Вкраина", и "Украйна", и "Украина" (замствованное из польского, там с ударением не забалуешь). У Пушкина - ""укрАинская ночь" Словари стали комплиментарными современной Украине, там только "украИнец". Жизнь покажет, стоит ли русским изменить ударение.