# Улица Украинская

Tags: орфоэпия

Скажите, где ставится ударение: улица УкраИнская или улица УкрАинская и почему. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Надо спрашивать у местных или узнавать этимологию. Если улица названа в честь Украины, то ударение на "и", если от украина (окраина), то на "а". Первый вариант вероятнее.

Answer (score 0):

УкраИнская улица на русском. А на Украинском(не знаю) в такт УкрАинская,там , мне кажется, без разницы. В доказательство: УкраИна, УкраИнский. УкрАина - так ударение поставить нельзя, потому что слово приобретёт значение "У края".

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ставить ударение на *и*. Прочитайте [это](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/47495-kak-pravilno-ukrainskiy-ili-ukrainskiy/), а также изучите [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17851/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Answer (score 0):

Это могут наверняка сказать только местные топонимисты.

По-хорошему-то, конечно, прилагательное должно иметь вид Укра**и**нская (если связано с Украиной) - и если Вы не знаете наверняка, что здесь что-то особенное, то лучше этим вариантом и пользоваться.

Но дело в том, что топонимы далеко не всегда следуют нормам языка, на котором дано название. Причин тому много, соседи прочих - традиция (Ан**и**чков мост в Спб), сохранение в топониме устаревшего варианта (ул. План**ё**рная в Москве), ошибочное переосмысление названия (как с "ул. Бармалеева" в Спб) и многое другое.